#  A few things about division by zero in C

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Value returning 1.#INF000](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8488841/value-returning-1-inf000)

I always thought division by 0 would result in a compiled program crashing

However I discovered today (using VC++ 2010 Express) that division by 0 gives something called 1.#INF000 and it is supposed to be positive infinity

When it was passed to a function, it got passed as -1.#IND000

What is this all about?

Searching 1.#INF000 and -1.#IND000 on google do not provide any clear explanations either

Is it just something specific to VC++ ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8488841/value-returning-1-inf000

Comment: `1.#IND000` is the representation of `NaN` AFAIK.

Comment: @nneonneo http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9883128/what-does-1-ind000-mean-in-visual-studio-debug-window

Comment: @Will there was nothing in the question that suggested the division is of a floating point.

Comment: I thought the fact that the result was 1.#INF000, a floating point value, would imply the division was floating point. Otherwise it would be an undefined integer value surely?

Comment: @Will if the behavior is undefined, any value is valid without any implications on the types of the operands. And in this case it is. It makes no difference whether the right operand is int of float.

Comment: `1,#INF000` and `1.#IND000` is __not__ legal representations of anything.  The standard requires `Inf` or `Infinity` for infinity, and `Nan` for not a number (supposing, of course, the implementation supports these values).  This is a serious bug in VC++, and causes no end of problems (especially because no other program will read them back as infinity or not a number).

Comment: When in doubt, use an `int`.  You're much more likely to get a satisfying crash.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Floating point division by zero behaves differently than integer division by zero.

[The IEEE floating point standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_by_zero#In_computer_arithmetic) differentiates between +inf and -inf, while integers cannot store infinity. Integer division by zero results in undefined behaviour. Floating point division by zero is defined by the floating point standard and results in +inf or -inf.

**Edit:**

As pointed out by Luchian, C++ implementations are not required to follow the IEEE Floating point standard. If the implementation you use doesn't follow the IEEE Floating point standard the result of floating point division by zero is undefined.

Comment: C++ is described by the C++ standard.

Comment: Ironically, under default settings, processes in Linux get a SIGFPE ("floating point exception") for dividing integers by zero, but not dividing floats by zero...

Comment: The result is NaN if the dividend is zero.

Comment: @nneonneo but the code is `FPE_INTDIV` for *integer division by zero*.

Comment: Yes, I know, but it's still funny (to me, maybe).

Comment: @LuchianGrigore in what is this answer wrong?

Comment: @ouah the result is undefined. The behavior is undefined.

Comment: @iammilind Why is this answer correct?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: if `std::numeric_limits<double>::is_iec559` is true, then the `double` behavior must follow IEEE 754 rules. all the machinery that is there for checking e.g. NaN (in C++11), would be meaningless if not for this. so there's a **defect** in the standard regarding the wording about "undefined" behavior. because UB in standardese means no requirements on an implementation, while later on the standard does impose such requirements (conditionally).

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf regardless, this answer is not conditioned by this, as it is now. Still wrong.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: That an answer is incomplete does not make it wrong. I think OP was looking for an explanation for the observed behaviour, not lawyering about standards.

Comment: @Joren if the level of incompleteness affect its validity, sure it does. (didn't see the edit until now)

Answer (score 12):

Edit: The question is about C++ and the result in C++ is undefined, as **clearly stated by the standard**, not the IEEE or whatever other entity that doesn't, in fact, regulate the C++ language. The standard does. C++ implementations *might* follow IEEE rules, but in this case it's clear the behavior is undefined.

> I always thought division by 0 would result in a compiled program crashing

Nope, it results in undefined behavior. Anything can happen, a crash is not guaranteed.

According to the C++ Standard:

#### 5.6 Multiplicative operators

> 4) The binary / operator yields the quotient, and the binary %
>   operator yields the remainder from the division of the first
>       expression by the second. **If the second operand of / or % is zero the behavior is undefined**; otherwise (a/b)*b + a%b
>       is equal to a. If both operands are nonnegative then the remainder is nonnegative; if not, the sign of the remainder is
>       implementation-defined79). (emphasis mine)

Comment: The great thing about undefined behaviour is that the compiler can do anything it wants. Even things that are completely unrelated to the undefined behaviour, i's best avoided at all times.

Comment: Only integer division by zero results in undefined behaviour. According to the result this must be floating point division.

Comment: @KlasLindbäck see edit. The question is about C++.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the responses. I'm sorry it's not clear from my question; I am using VC++ but the code is C code, however the source file has the extension cpp so I think it may be invoking the c++ copiler

Comment: @LuchianGrigore, So is Klas' answer above right?

Answer (score 11):

Quoting the [latest draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) of the ISO C++ standard, section 5.6 ([expr.mul]):

> If the second operand of / or % is zero the behavior is undefined.

This applies to both integer and floating-point division.

A particular C++ implementation may conform to the [IEEE floating-point standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating-point), which has more specific requirements for division by zero, which which case the behavior may be well defined *for that implementation*. That's probably why floating-point division by zero yields Infinity in your implementation. But the C++ standard doesn't require IEEE floating-point behavior.

Comment: Is floating point divide by zero undefined for C as well?

Comment: @Pacerier: Yes. N1570 6.5.5p5: "In both operations, if the value of
the second operand is zero, the behavior is undefined." (referring to `/` and `%`)

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following code sniplet in C.
it throws the exception. it works on linux donno about windows though

```
#include <fenv.h>

#include <TRandom.h>
static void __attribute__ ((constructor)) trapfpe(void)
{
    /* Enable some exceptions. At startup all exceptions are masked. */
    feenableexcept(FE_INVALID|FE_DIVBYZERO|FE_OVERFLOW);
}
```