# How does C++ deal with NAN? Is there a standard way or is compiler dependent?

Tags: c++, floating-point, nan

In a program that needs to process sin(x)/x function, I encountered NAN problem, I simplified the problem in the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

int main()
{
    std::cout.precision(15);

    //This line compiles and run in g++, but does not compile in Visual Studio 2013
    std::cout << 0.0/0.0 << std::endl;

    //This line compiles and run in both g++ and VS2013
    std::cout << std::sin(0.0)/0.0 << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

In g++, the output is: -nan   -nan, in VS2013, the output is: -1.IND, because the first line does not compile so I commented it out.

My questions are:

1. What does this '-1.IND' mean?
2. It seems NAN processing is compiler dependent, should this be standardized in C++? Why?
3. I used this hack to deal with this problem:

   ```
   double sinc(double x)
   {
       if(x == 0.0)
           return 1.0;
       return std::sin(x)/x;
   }
   ```

Is this the right way?

EDIT: another question, 4. why VS2013 deal with 0.0/0.0 and sin(0.0)/0.0 differently?

Comment: 1. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/347920/what-do-1-inf00-1-ind00-and-1-ind-mean 2. it is (I'm just not sure it also says how nan should be converted to string, which is probably what you are seeing, because of 1) 3. do you have a reason to think it is incorrect (apart from the fact that you must not compare floating point numbers like that)?

Comment: `NaN` behavior *is* standardized, in the [IEEE Floating Point standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point).

Comment: so, why VS2013 and g++8.4 deal with 0.0/0.0 differently? which one is correct? and, why VS2013 deal with 0.0/0.0 and sin(0.0)/0.0 differently?

Comment: BTW - I think the "hack" is mathematically correct for this function. It might even be described as sensible - apart from == on doubles... Perhaps if it;s "near" zero that's good enough.

Comment: Is it the display of the `NaN` that concerns you? They can be displayed differently varying between platforms etc. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN#Display

Comment: The way to establish if something is "near" zero would be to use something like the http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/epsilon

Comment: @user465139 In this case you don't need to check if x is near 0 but if x **is** 0. You can use == for **exact** representation.

Comment: much thanks, and, does it mean that 0.0 is not always the same even in the same machine?

Comment: Sorry, that was for the comment above. I believe there is exatly two representation of 0 : -0 and +0 that are equal. But I think for 4) that VS probably handles only particuliar cases of `.../0`.

Comment: speaking about near zero and things; [boost::interval](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/numeric/interval/doc/interval.htm) could be worth a look

Comment: *In this case* it's safe to divide by almost-zero as the numerator is less or equal to 1.0.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Exactly what I said...

Comment: OK, then I don't understand the second part of your comment. Never mind.

Comment: Your "hack" isn't a hack; it's exactly how you should implement `sinc`.

Comment: @doctorlove: No, using `==` is entirely correct here.

Comment: @Gall, @tmyklebu: It is _very_ _important_ to remember that _in_ _general_ floating-point equality comparisons guarding against division by zero should involve setting a tolerance first. In this particular case, any sensible implementation of `sin(x)` would use the approximation `sin(x) == x` when `x` is very close to 0.0, thus checking for the exact equality `x == 0.0` is sufficient.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are similar questions to yours answered on SO:

> 1.What does this '-1.IND' mean?

See [What do 1.#INF00, -1.#IND00 and -1.#IND mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347920/what-do-1-inf00-1-ind00-and-1-ind-mean?)

> 2.It seems NAN processing is compiler dependent, should this be standardized in C++? Why?

See [A few things about division by zero in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12617408/a-few-things-about-division-by-zero-in-c) (it says C, but it talks about C++)

> 3.I used this hack to deal with this problem:
>
> ```
> double sinc(double x) {
>
>     if(x == 0.0)
>         return 1.0;
>     return std::sin(x)/x; 
> }
> ```
>
> Is this the right way?

Yes, this implementation of the [sinc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinc_function) function will work and (Thanks to @MSalters for the comment) is mathematically correct; however, keep in mind that, while it will work for this case, don't make a habit of comparing `double` types with `==`.

Comment: Much thanks, and I think sin(0.0)/0.0 = 1 is the correct behaviour.

Comment: @Nasser:`sinc(0)` is defined to be 1, and mathematically it's just the same exception to the rule as it's in C++. It's not a limit.

Comment: @MSalters ah! I just looked it up, and it appears you're right. Thanks, will fix it now.

Comment: @MSalters and David, since you seem to be veterans, is it alright that my answer is 2/3 links to other SO posts? I've gotten some criticism before because "the links could break one day" but I didn't want to copy content from other answers. What's the verdict on this?

Comment: About `1.#…`, see also http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/02/28/10397976.aspx

Comment: @MSalters You are right. I'll remove the comment. Testing `x == 0` is the correct thing to do

Comment: @Nasser: not a veteran either, but I think that onsite links (i.e. to other SO answers) should be fine. Offsite links are much more likely to disappear.

Comment: @Nasser It's fine. SO won't ever break in-site links.

Comment: Comparing `double`s with `==` is perfectly sensible in lots and lots of cases.  Especially this one.

Comment: @tmyklebu: The reason that `==` is okay here is a bit subtle, though:  if the expression had been `sin(pi*x) / x` then for a library-quality implementation you'd want to special-case subnormals to avoid loss of precision in the `pi * x` intermediate result.  So it would be appropriate to have an `if(abs(x) < 1e-300)`-like guard in place of the equality.  We're okay here because `sin(x)` is going to give exactly `x` for tiny `x`, with no significant precision loss.

Comment: Then again, perhaps I'm overthinking this.

Answer (score 5):

To add an answer for (4), `sin(x)` is a runtime function, and thus `sin(0.0)/0.0` is handled as an expression which is evaluated at runtime. OTOH, `0.0/0.0` is handled fully by the compiler, which is why it spots the problem. An implementation detail of your Visual Studio version, and not something on which you can count.

Answer (score 3):

Complete conformance to the IEEE floating point standard is *optional* in the C and C++ standards.  This is because, for reasons which have never been clear to me, CPU designers **hate** the IEEE floating point standard.  I am not aware of *any* CPU that implements the entire specification correctly and efficiently.  (The best you can have, as far as I know, is a CPU that's fast and correct for normal finite numbers but suffers multiple-orders-of-magnitude slowdowns if you want to work with denormals, infinity, and NaN.)

The C and C++ standards are written by compiler people.  Compiler people want to be able to generate machine code that runs fast on real CPUs, and they know real CPUs cut corners on IEEE floating point, so they don't make full IEEE floating point conformance a language requirement.

Comment: Stalls for Infinity and NaN *mostly* went away ~15 years ago.  FPUs on all modern architectures handle them at speed.  Stalls for subnormal values are starting to go away now as well; *some* subnormal cases are already handled at speed on the most recent processors.  (That aside, +1 for pointing out that conformance is optional, but in my experience this has less to do with current CPU designers—who have largely resigned themselves to supporting IEEE-754—and more to do with compiler writers who want to support legacy hardware).

Comment: @StephenCanon: Not just legacy hardware--many embedded systems require a sufficiently small amount of floating-point math that floating-point hardware would represent a waste of resources.  If a program will need to update a display twice per second, and each update requires a half-dozen floating-point operations, floating-point hardware would offer zero benefit to justify the cost.  In the absence of floating-point hardware, special-case code for things like subnormals will make code bigger and slower than code that simply truncates subnormals to zero.

Comment: @supercat: If the system does so little FP that it doesn't require floating-point hardware, then it does so little FP that it can afford to use a correct software implementation (and if it's really in no man's land--which I've never encountered despite writing FP code for systems on both sides of the divide my whole career--a toolchain is free to provide a skanky version of the libraries as an option; IEEE-754 doesn't disallow that).  Is it a big pile of work?  Yes, and I can understand resisting it.  Is it impossible?  Absolutely not.

Comment: @StephenCanon: If the system has a total of 2K of code space to play with (I've used ones that were smaller, though I haven't tried to do floating-point math on them), it may not be able to afford the code necessary to accommodate denormals even if it was only doing one floating-point operation per day.  I would guess that 99% of software-floating-point applications would be better served with an FP library that was smaller and didn't handle denormals, than one which was fully IEEE-754 compliant but was bigger as a consequence.

Comment: @supercat: A system that has a total of 2K of code space to play with is probably better off not carrying around a floating-point library and doing "one operation a day" in integer instead.  I'm not  saying that there are never situations where one wants to have skanky soft-float; I'm saying that in those situations one could choose to use a library other than a IEEE-754 version even if C required it be available.

Comment: @StephenCanon The thing I've never understood (and I'm not at all a hardware person, so I'm prepared to believe there's a good reason I don't know about) is why it is difficult to handle denormals at speed. Naively, it seems like it should be a single special case in the logic for aligning mantissae prior to whatever arithmetic operation you're about to do.

Comment: @Zack: It’s not *hard*, exactly, it’s just more complexity and area, which could otherwise be used for something else; hardware designers are [generally] extremely careful with how they spend their area budget, and want to make sure they’re getting the most possible benefit for it; denormals are relatively rare in *most* code, so it’s somewhat challenging to make the case for spending area to make them fast.

Comment: @StephenCanon I guess the question is why it is more than a *trivial* amount of extra complexity and area.

Comment: @Zack: It’s a barrel shifter or something similar where there wouldn’t ordinarily be one (at least for multiplication inputs and results; you can likely do something clever for addition inputs); shifters aren’t enormous, but that’s something like 300 multiplexers, plus enough additional delay that it would have a good chance of adding a cycle of latency to *all* fp operations if you try to handle it on the main path, whether or not any denormals are involved.

Answer (score 2):

1. Compilation of expression `double res = 0.0 / 0.0` fails because compiler tries to optimize the code it determines "invalid" expression. It can't optimize expression like `sin(x) / 0.0` because it's not able to simplify and "optimize" code like this".
2. Displaying special values of `double` data type is platform dependent. But representation is *architecture* dependent. To check this you can run this function on different architectures:

   `template<typename T>
   void inspect(T v1, T v2)
   {
       T i_val = v1;
       i_val /= v2;
       size_t len = sizeof(T);
       int* bit_repr = (int*)(&i_val);
       for (int i = 0; i < (len /  sizeof(int)); i ++)
       {
           std::bitset<sizeof(int) * 8> bs(*(bit_repr + i));
           std::cout << bs;
       }
       std::cout << std::endl;
   }`

Call previous function with following arguments:

```
inspect<double>(0.0, 0.0);
inspect<double>(1.0, 0.0);
inspect<double>(-1.0, 0.0);
```

Comment: impressive answer, I run this code and got this output(I added a ' -- ' between integers)     00000000000000000000000000000000 -- 11111111111110000000000000000000

00000000000000000000000000000000 -- 01111111111100000000000000000000

00000000000000000000000000000000 -- 11111111111100000000000000000000   Yet I am still a little confused about this, does this mean +nan, -nan, and +nan, respectively?

Comment: Here is output I've got:
`
0000000000000000000000000000000011111111111110000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000001111111111100000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000011111111111100000000000000000000
`
And I think this means:
[sign]111111111111[NaN/Inf]
NaN represented as "positive" number
last 2 lines +/-INF's
Note: not +/- NaN, but +/- INF(infinity)

Answer (score 1):

This might be helpful :
C++ 11 (so VS2013) has some feature to understand if a given number is NAN or is finite.
Use std::isnan() or std::isfinite()