# C++; Floating Point exception; Without ./ operator

Tags: c++, loops, opencv, mat

The example below, is from OpenCv documentation[1].

```
Mat H(100, 100, CV_64F);
for(int i = 0; i < H.rows; i++)
    for(int j = 0; j < H.cols; j++)
        H.at<double>(i,j)=1./(i+j);
```

This works perfectly fine. But in the last line what is ./ operator? And if I replace it with / it gives me floating point exception.

So, in both cases we have infinity when i and j are 0; then why do we get floating point exception for the second case?

[1] http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html

Comment: please suggest improvements to this question. thanks

Comment: If you got it, I could delete my answer so you'll be able to delete you post. Just say the word.

Comment: @StoryTeller I think its a good answer, please don't delete it. It would help the community. I am waiting for few more answers. Why do you want to delete it (i am just curious)?

Comment: Had you wanted to delete your question, my post would prevent it because it's upvoted. So just wanted to give you the option if this attracts a heap of downvotes.

Comment: @StoryTeller I really appreciate your intent :)

Comment: I can't reproduce `floating-point-exception` for code as supplied -- even if changing `./` to `/`.  Nevertheless, I suggest you replace the assignment with a `cerr<<` in order to see what values are generated in each case.

Comment: ...I'm guessing the error was generated when you excluded the `+1` in `(i+j+1)`.

Comment: @nobar Yes you are right it was generated when i did 1/(i+j)

Comment: @nobar So, in both cases we have infinity when i and j are 0; then why do we get floating point exception for the second case?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12617540

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155675/discussion-between-nikhil-and-nobar).

Answer (score 4):

`./` is not an operator. The dot binds with the `1`, making it a double constant. It's equivalent to this:

```
1.0 / (i+j+1)
```

Only a bit shorter.

When you omit the dot, the expression is evaluated using integer arithmetic, giving all zero for all entries but `0, 0`.

Comment: Less well known is the /. operator, which open sources your website.

Answer (score 2):

The `.` character is part of the `1.` double literal. `/` is an arithmetic operator so the right hand side expression becomes:

```
1. / (i+j+1);
```

and the result is a value of type double.
Omitting the `.` character makes it an integer literal of `1` and the expression becomes:

```
1 / (i+j+1);
```

where both operands are integer values and the result is an integer value.  Spaces in C++ code make no difference to compiler. For readability reasons the statement should include spaces where appropriate:

```
H.at<double>(i,j) = 1. / (i+j+1);
```